# Error when attempting a PUT against /users/USERID endpoint in 2.0 API

Tags: box-api

I've seen others with the same issue ... I get the following json error message back whenever I attempt to disable a user or update their title.  Has anyone had luck with this?

I have no problems with the POST method to add an email_alias, or with the PUT method to move a users folder from one owner to another. I've tried it in perl and in curl (see below example session) So I'm relatively confident that :

1. I have a valid, OAuth2 bearer token
2. I have properly formed content and URLs

So, I'm trying to post to:

```
PUT /2.0/users/XXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

{"type":"error","status":400,"code":"invalid_request_parameters","help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Invalid input parameters in request","request_id":"1682580609514902d69b5fd"}
```

Update:  below is a trace from curl showing the request body:

```
0000: PUT /2.0/users/USERID HTTP/1.1  
00a2: Authorization: Bearer TOKEN  
011f:
=> Send data, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: {"status" : "inactive"}
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
<= Recv data, 207 bytes (0xcf)
0000: {"type":"error","status":400,"code":"invalid_request_parameters"
0040: ,"help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","messag
0080: e":"Invalid input parameters in request","request_id":"718513715
00c0: 514916f1109c2"}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, it'd be helpful if you could include the PUT request body.

Comment: updated with trace-ascii output from curl ... essentially, just trying to update the user by PUTing this content { "status":"inactive" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to the 4xx errors on PUTs :  the OAuth2 settings for the application in box needed to have "Manage Enterprise" checked ... my app has been around since the pre-OAuth2 days, wasnt aware of this flag.

After checking it, i get 200 response ... some PUT operations still dont effectively change the attribute, but they return a 2xx response, so, one hurdle cleared.

Comment: additional update ... although the data format for Box 2.0 API is json, don't POST or PUT with Content-type: application/json ... hasnt been working for me ... returns 200, but nothing is updated.